# CakePHP - Error saving form with partial table data to database

Tags: php, mysql, forms, cakephp

I have a new user form in CakePHP 3 that gathers basic data from the user, such as username, email, name, phone, etc. This is supposed to be saved to the `Users` table, which has additional data to that gathered in the form, such as if the account is an admin, the timestamp the account was created, etc. All of these other fields have default values specified in the database, such as `0` for `false` on the admin field, or `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` for the timestamp. The others I'm not saving from the form are nullable with no default values.

The issue I'm having is when the form is submitted, it returns the generic error `The user could not be saved. Please, try again`. I've used `print_r` to gather the `request` data as well as `debug()` for the `$user` data, and the `request` looks good, while `$user` has `This field is required` for the data for which I wanted the database to insert the default values.

What am I doing wrong, and why won't the form submit the values I give and the database set the defaults for the rest?

My controller:

```
    public function signup() {
        // set page-specific values
        $this->set('cakePage', false);

        if (!$this->request->session()->check('Session.timestamp')) {
            $this->redirect('/signup/home');
        }

        $user = $this->Users->newEntity();
        if ($this->request->is('post')) {
            $dob = implode("-", $this->request->data['birth_date']);
            $this->request->data['birth_date'] = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($dob));
            $user = $this->Users->patchEntity($user, $this->request->data);
            if ($this->Users->save($user)) {
                $this->Flash->success(__('The user has been saved.'));

                return $this->redirect(['action' => 'index']);
            } else {
                $this->Flash->error(__('The user could not be saved. Please, try again.'));

                // debug
                print_r($this->request->data);
                echo "<br>";
                print_r($user);
            }
        }
        $carriers = $this->Users->Carriers->find();
        $this->set(compact('user', 'carriers'));
        $this->set('_serialize', ['user']);
    }
```

Results of `print_r($this->request->data);`

```
Array ( [username] => asdf [password] => asdf [email] => asdf@gmail.com 
  [first_name] => asdf [last_name] => asdf [birth_date] => 2000-01-01 
  [profile_image] => testUrl [bio] => Yo [phone] => 1234567890 [carrier] => 1 )
```

Results of `debug($user);`

```
object(App\Model\Entity\User) {

    'username' => 'asdf',
    'password' => '$2y$10$HHCtvYKGBCnMyTVj3WoRk.qQQdb50x/8NYuHbAaDgeCSprS5Lj0kG',
    'email' => 'asdf@gmail.com',
    'first_name' => 'asdf',
    'last_name' => 'asdf',
    'birth_date' => object(Cake\I18n\FrozenDate) {

        'time' => '2000-01-01T00:00:00+00:00',
        'timezone' => 'UTC',
        'fixedNowTime' => false

    },
    'profile_image' => 'testUrl',
    'bio' => 'asdf',
    'phone' => (int) 1234567890,
    '[new]' => true,
    '[accessible]' => [
        '*' => true
    ],
    '[dirty]' => [
        'username' => true,
        'password' => true,
        'email' => true,
        'first_name' => true,
        'last_name' => true,
        'birth_date' => true,
        'profile_image' => true,
        'bio' => true,
        'phone' => true
    ],
    '[original]' => [],
    '[virtual]' => [],
    '[errors]' => [
        'private' => [
            '_required' => 'This field is required'
        ],
        'admin' => [
            '_required' => 'This field is required'
        ],
        'joined_timestamp' => [
            '_required' => 'This field is required'
        ],
        'updated_timestamp' => [
            '_required' => 'This field is required'
        ],
        'active' => [
            '_required' => 'This field is required'
        ],
        'account_status' => [
            '_required' => 'This field is required'
        ]
    ],
    '[invalid]' => [],
    '[repository]' => 'Users'

}
```

Comment: Please use `debug()` instead of `print_r()`, that stuff is horribly unreadable...

Comment: Updated with the results of `debug()`

Comment: you have one field in your $this->request->data named as 'carrier' which is missing from $user entity . Are you sure it is not mandatory and set to some default value in your database?

Comment: I'm unsure why that's not appearing -- it is madatory, but it's a foreign key for a table of carrier data. I did get this data to insert into the database, but by commenting out the validation code for `private`, `admin`, etc. I'm still not sure if this is how I want to do it, but when submitting the data, `carrier` is saved correctly despite not appearing in the `$user` entity.